# IPAD PRO 2021 (M1) - PROBLEM PROVISIONING PROFILE

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile

sorry for my English.

I have an APP distributed in AddHoc for Ipad / Iphone. (In Xamarin.Forms)

The process I do is, Add the Device ID in Devices (On developer.apple.com), then i go to provisioning profiles, edit te provisioning profile and check the new Device to enable it.

Now i have a problem with the Ipad Pro 2021, i can't add the device as a IOs, i only can add it as MAC. Ok. But when I go to the provisioning profile and check the devices list i can't add the device, I have an option saying (Include mac devices) this option is enabled but i can't see my device.

Anyone can help me? What I'm doing wrong?

Best Regards.

Comment: Does it work on other device? or just this ipad pro?

Comment: It works in all other devices (Ipad mini, Ipad pro 2018...) The only device with problems is the Ipad Pro 2021 (With the M1)

Comment: You could post an issue on github https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues